# Isolation from the internet - subnetting

Tags: networking

I'm covering a little bit of networking and I'm onto the topic of subnetting. One of the end of chapter exercises has me stumped. It looks easy but I've got nothing. The exercise is as follows:

> Explain how subnet 2 can be isolated from the internet (i.e. unable to
>   send/recive packets to/from the internet but able to exchange packets
>   with the other subnets (fill in the corresponding part of the routing
>   tables of the appropriate routers in the format shown below)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

The subnet (simplified):

```
*********    *********
* SUB 1 *    * SUB 2 *
*********    *********
    \           /
     \         /
      \       /
      #########   *********
      #ROUTER1#   * SUB 3 *
      #########   *********
          |        /
          |       /
      #########  /
      #ROUTER2#_/
      #########
          |
          |
   To/From Internet
```

The Table:

```
Source NetID  |  Destination NetID  |  Action
---------------------------------------------------
              |                     |
              |                     |
```

Note, I was going to post this on serverexchange but apprently SO is the place to ask high level questions networking like this?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

- SUB 1: 1.0.0.0/8
- SUB 2: 2.0.0.0/8
- SUB 3: 3.0.0.0/8

Router1:

- 1.0.0.0 -> 2.0.0.0: Send to 2.0.0.0
- 1.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0: Send to Router2's IP address
- 2.0.0.0 -> 1.0.0.0: Send to 1.0.0.0
- 2.0.0.0 -> 3.0.0.0: Send to Router2's IP address

Router2:

- 1.0.0.0 -> 3.0.0.0: Send to 3.0.0.0
- 1.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0: Send to Internet
- 2.0.0.0 -> 3.0.0.0: Send to 3.0.0.0
- 3.0.0.0 -> 1.0.0.0: Send to Router1's IP address
- 3.0.0.0 -> 2.0.0.0: Send to Router1's IP address
- 3.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0: Send to Internet

The trick is the absence of a default route for anything originating from 2.0.0.0/8 on both routers.